# IoT Analytics Datastore is empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-core, aws-iot-analytics

Sorry for my english, I'm trying to get better, thank you.

I'm trying to use IoT Analytics from AWS Services. However, after I properly created the channel, I'm now stuck with the pipeline and datastore.

First, on pipeline there is an error on the monitoring: ActivityExecutionError-DatastoreActivity-16

I can't find anywhere some troubleshooting for this error.

The consequence of this error is that the datastore is completely empty and the dataset SQL queries does not work since it can't find any data.

Have anyone found the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

probably you have an error with the pipeline. Either the pipeline does not have the right role to execute the actions or the activities are wrong (for example you try to enrich incoming data using the wrong field).